# python error in opencv installation

Tags: python, opencv, build, cmake

I am attempting to install the opencv library in Linux and I get the following error in a log generated by a python script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmcleod/opencv-2.4.4/modules/java/generator/gen_javadoc.py", line 257, in ?
    import hdr_parser
  File "/tmcleod/opencv-2.4.4/modules/java/generator/../../python/src2/hdr_parser.py", line 641
    decl[1] = ": " + ", ".join([b if "::" in b else self.get_dotted_name(b).replace(".","::") for b in bases])
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the command in the makefile that is causing the error:

```
cd /tmcleod/opencv-2.4.4/release/modules/java && /usr/bin/python2 /tmcleod/opencv-2.4.4/modules/java/generator/gen_javadoc.py --modules core,imgproc,objdetect,features2d,video,highgui,ml,calib3d,photo,contrib /tmcleod/opencv-2.4.4/modules/java/generator/src/java /tmcleod/opencv-2.4.4/release/modules/java 2>"/tmcleod/opencv-2.4.4/release/modules/java/get_javadoc_errors.log"
```

I do not know why I need to generate java docs on the installation of a C++ library, but the issue is causing the build to fail. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I had the same exact issue. I only needed the python library, so as a work-around, I copied the compiled shared object file (cv2.so), into my working directory.

Comment: @Moshe, so is it an error in the python script?

Comment: Possibly, although that syntax appears to be legal for Python 2.7, so I don't know what is wrong (I used `[b if b in 'abc' else 'X' for b in 'abcdefgh']` as a small test case).

Answer (score 3):

The problem here was that cmake was finding an older version (2.4) of the python executable that did not understand this construct. The workaround is to pass cmake a path to python. From
opencv extract directory:

```
$ mkdir release
$ cd release
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./build -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/tmcleod/Python-2.7.3/python ..
$ make
$ make install
```